# What would be an apache2 rewrite rule to redirect /sub to a port?

Tags: mod-rewrite, configuration, url-rewriting, apache2

I have 2 web applications installed in the same server, and want to use the same domain for both.

I already have an apache2 running on port 80, and both apps running on ports 8081 and 8082 respectively.

I'm having trouble configuring the the rewrite rule to accomplish the following:

When the user goes to ://domain/aaa I'd like to (silently) rewrite to ://localhost:8082/aaa, and when the user goes to ://domain/sub/aaa, to rewrite to ://localhost:8083/aaa

How can I accomplish that? (of course the user should not be aware of the redirect, as in, the url in the browser should remain the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more then just mod_rewrite to do this. One way of doing this is by setting up a reverse proxy with mod_proxy for two virtual hosts (one each app) that include something like:

```
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass / http://domain:8082/app/
ProxyPassReverse / http://domain:8083/app/
```